# May RSA-PSS DB MSB be 1?

Tags: rsa, openssl, rsa-pss

I've used OpenSSL to generate an RSA-PSS keypair.

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBUgIBADALBgkqhkiG9w0BAQoEggE+MIIBOgIBAAJBAKjJmhflBebbRJt0JNWe
elk9w32jGxvZrvxO7kdpvNFWCgXIXSU0zC26R2Rca1w81sY4MpKfKl0baIK06Dbp
F6cCAwEAAQJANfamrocJeQKXj7/1WtrdMRT/IHb6XtAdEwvFQM28kYyUU4QuIxGO
cJ90rX99FdhOouUtbeYVXfnR7+I4NL6C+QIhAN6GukudUZqsor+AH/fuVg1Z4cUo
8slDhv5hoHJq1HizAiEAwi1yKT4YeBWc7vxwBwQ5i2DtrhfOxOs1+Mzij7xu1z0C
IQCqekz+4OdDuD52t5HGP7FtSQ7OHTDjP/iLqf9hqLZeQQIgf7DVBuwPuUA1QC9/
GA4eLVrjUf3T+kjW6DMLtgvrM90CIGAwntt2VAvNb2rCNMsLqtkM0iLGGopRkXqW
hkb6wXFX
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm signing a short message (the text "RSA-PSS") using OpenSSL with SHA256 and validating that signature by hand:

```
$ cat hash_value | openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey rsapsskey.pem -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -pkeyopt rsa_pss_saltlen:30 >signature
```

In some instances the MSB of the DB is set to 1, i.e., the block begins with 0x80 instead of 0x00. If the seed fills the whole DB, the separating byte 0x01 becomes 0x81. For example:

$s$ = `3193b488a362a71b7b1fb4328a3f2eea2423f762a87ad9823b01c21e1fe7296a3d4530513945c8b59f30427fa9c9c60340d20320d10a0f21290669060b833b83`

$s^e \mod n$ = `64f252e4a9dc625f881b87010ab54c5dc557fac18ff11573621e92aa68415067c12e5a3c85aafe33c90a7fd352ddb5c0dcada72268c55d74cc034fe9ff54b9bc`

mDB = `64f252e4a9dc625f881b87010ab54c5dc557fac18ff11573621e92aa684150`

mask = `e58271cfa607b848676d08342483e8e57aee64c76853f2a09944f6a731d2a7`

DB = `8170232b0fdbda17ef768f352e36a4b8bfb99e06e7a2e7d3fb5a640d5993f7`

seed = `70232b0fdbda17ef768f352e36a4b8bfb99e06e7a2e7d3fb5a640d5993f7`

$m'$ = `000000000000000068c8e017fdb4880b0b276605be9003f9cb6a9504b8b83edac2ccf9d0de420ca170232b0fdbda17ef768f352e36a4b8bfb99e06e7a2e7d3fb5a640d5993f7`

$H(m')$ = `67c12e5a3c85aafe33c90a7fd352ddb5c0dcada72268c55d74cc034fe9ff54b9`

I.e., signature verification works, but why is the first byte of DB 0x81 instead of 0x01? I cannot find a reference to that behavior in RFC8017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use [PKCS#1v2.2](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr) (RSA Laboratories edition) as a reference.

Looking a the [private key with an ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBUgIBADALBgkqhkiG9w0BAQoEggE-MIIBOgIBAAJBAKjJmhflBebbRJt0JNWeelk9w32jGxvZrvxO7kdpvNFWCgXIXSU0zC26R2Rca1w81sY4MpKfKl0baIK06DbpF6cCAwEAAQJANfamrocJeQKXj7_1WtrdMRT_IHb6XtAdEwvFQM28kYyUU4QuIxGOcJ90rX99FdhOouUtbeYVXfnR7-I4NL6C-QIhAN6GukudUZqsor-AH_fuVg1Z4cUo8slDhv5hoHJq1HizAiEAwi1yKT4YeBWc7vxwBwQ5i2DtrhfOxOs1-Mzij7xu1z0CIQCqekz-4OdDuD52t5HGP7FtSQ7OHTDjP_iLqf9hqLZeQQIgf7DVBuwPuUA1QC9_GA4eLVrjUf3T-kjW6DMLtgvrM90CIGAwntt2VAvNb2rCNMsLqtkM0iLGGopRkXqWhkb6wXFX), the public modulus $n$ is 512-bit, thus in [RSASSA-PSS-VERIFY](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A84%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C126%2C273%2Cnull%5D) we have $modBits\,=\,512$, $k=64$.

Thus in [EMSA-PSS-VERIFY](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A111%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C126%2C644%2Cnull%5D) we have $emBits\,=\,modBits\;-\,1\,=\,511$.  $EM$ is the question's 64-octet string following $s^e\,\bmod n$.  $emLen\,=\,\lceil\,emBits\,/\,8\,\rceil\,=\,64$.  The hash is SHA-256, thus $hLen\,=\,32$.  The question's salt is 30 octets, thus $sLen\,=\,30$.  The constraint $emBits\,\ge\,8\,hLen\,+\,8\,sLen\,+\,9$ is met (with an extra $7$ bits).

At [EMSA-PSS-VERIFY](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A111%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C126%2C644%2Cnull%5D) step 3, $emLen\,\ge\,hLen+\,sLen\,+\,2$, the check passes.

At step 4, the rightmost octet of $EM$ has hexadecimal value $\text{0xbc}$, the check passes.

At step 5, $maskedDB$ is the leftmost $emLen\;-\,hLen\;-\,1\,=\,31$ octets, as "mDB" in the question.

At step 6, it is considered the $8\,emLen\;-\,emBits\,=\,1$ leftmost bit(s) of the leftmost octet of $maskedDB$. That octet is $\text{0x64}$, that bit is $0$, the check passes.

At step 7, $dbMask$ is the 31 octets of the question's "mask".

At step 8, $DB$ is the 31 octets of the question's "DB".

At step 9, it is set the leftmost $8\,emLen\;-\,emBits\,=\,1$ bit(s) of the leftmost octet in $DB$ to zero. That leftmost octet goes from $\text{0x81}$ to $\text{0x01}$.

---

> Why is the first byte of DB $\text{0x81}$ instead of $\text{0x01}$?

That first byte/leftmost octet is $\text{0x81}$ after step 8 because $dbMask$ is computed over an integer number of octets wide enough to perform the XOR of step 8, with $k\,+1\,\bmod\,8\,=\,1$ extra bit(s) if the left octet, which take pseudorandom value(s) in $dbMask$, thus in $DB$ after the XOR (which happens to be with zero bits, as checked at step 6). But these extra bit(s) in $DB$ get masked out to zero at step 9.

After that masking, the byte is $\text{0x01}$ because the signature is valid and the salt has been set to the maximum possible size $k\;-\,hLen\;-\,1$. It would be $\text{0x00}$ for any smaller salt size.

---

We can now answer the question in title:

> May RSA-PSS $DB$ Most Significant Bit be 1?

No for $DB$ as computed

- during signature generation, in [EMSA-PSS-ENCODE](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A108%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C126%2C721%2Cnull%5D) at step 8
- during signature verification, in [EMSA-PSS-VERIFY](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A111%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C126%2C644%2Cnull%5D) at step 9, if $k\,\bmod8\,\ne\,1$ (because then step 9 masks this Most Significant Bit) or if the signature is valid (because then this Most Significant Bit must be zero, which will be checked at step 10);

but possibly so for $DB$ as computed during signature verification in [EMSA-PSS-VERIFY](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A111%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C126%2C644%2Cnull%5D)

- at step 8 (irrespective of signature validity and value of $k$); this is what occurs in the question
- at step 9, though only for invalid signature and $k\,\bmod8\,=\,1$ (e.g. 2049-bit $n$). Notice that for such $k$, step 9 performs no masking, and step 10 will catch the signature as invalid if the Most Significant Bit of $DB$ happens to be 1.